# Unable to open VS solution for any libararies in dotnet/runtime in Visual Studio 2019 v16.7.6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-runtime

I downloaded the repository https://github.com/dotnet/runtime and followed this workflow guide https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/docs/workflow/README.md

After that, I ran the `build.cmd` from root directory of the repository. Took me a while to build the project but when I opened any of the Visual Studio solution from one of its libraries (i.e System.Text.Json.sln) I had this error: ***The project file cannot be opened. Version 5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.8.0 of MSBuild.***

I also downloaded the SDK for .NET 5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15.

Question: How can I have the MSBuild version 16.8.0 on Visual Studio 2019 v16.7.6? Or what am I missing?

Comment: More than likely you need the latest VS 2019 Preview version

Comment: Thanks @CamiloTerevinto. So there is no way to just port the required version of MS Build with the current version of Visual Studio I have?

Comment: @JesseGador: Likely not, especially since that repo _is_ the runtime itself. For other projects, you would likely be able to downgrade the compiler requirement, but that's not an option for the .NET core itself.

Comment: @PMF & CamiloTerevinto:
I could not thank you enough for your answers. This has been bugging me for days now. I will surely try to download the preview version of VS.

Answer (score 1):

Projects built against .NET Core 5.0, preview2 (as the one you have there) require Visual Studio 2019 preview. You can download it from Microsoft, it works with the same license as the official releases.